# Why some keystrokes are ignored?

Tags: keyboard, windows-8-preview, hardware-failure

I have a recent issue with a keyboard/mouse combo. Some keystrokes and mouse down/mouse up events are ignored; in other words, if I type: "Hello World", I may find myself with "Hllo World". Sometimes everything is ok for hours; sometimes, it may completely block the keyboard for a few seconds.

First, I thought that since this is a cordless keyboard/mouse combo, there is an issue with radio signal, especially since what I observe is very close to what would happen if the receiver is too far away from the keyboard/mouse or if something in the middle is blocking the signal.

It appeared that the problem is exactly the same with an ordinary, non-cordless keyboard.

How to diagnose this issue, keeping in mind that:

- The risk to have malware is pretty low and recent scans shown nothing,
- The PC has Windows 8 Consumer Preview,
- Windows was installed months ago, while the issue with the keyboard/mouse is recent (two weeks),
- There are no special drivers for keyboard/mouse to install/reinstall,
- The ordinary keyboard/mouse combo is used through USB. The other, non-cordless keyboard, uses PS/2,
- The mouse motion seems unaffected (but mouse buttons are affected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the Windows 8 On-screen keyboard work faultlessly?  If so it would point to a physical keyboard hardware problem.

I once had a problem with my laptop displaying different letters, but that was because of the Function key and I cured that by pressing the Num Lk/ Scr Lk key.

Comment: I already tried to determine if on-screen keyboard helps, but I can't test it reliably, since my mouse buttons fail too most of the time when keyboard fails.